Is the topological dimension of spacetime fixed for causally isomorphic spacetimes?
Suppose time-oriented spacetimes $(M_1 , g_1)$ and $(M_2, g_2)$ are not homeomorphic under their manifold topologies $\mathcal{M}_1$ and $\mathcal{M}_2$ respectively.
The Lorentzian metrics $g_1$ and $g_2$ induce binary relations $\ll_1$ and $\ll_2$ over their manifolds respectively which is defined as such:

$p \ll q \leftrightarrow$ there exists a time-like path connecting $p$ to $q$

Let's call the bijective map $\phi: M_1 \rightarrow M_2$ a $\ll$-isomorophism which means

$p \ll q$ if and only if $\phi(p) \ll \phi(q)$

Suppose that spacetimes $(M_1,g_1)$ and $(M_2,g_2)$ are $\ll$-isomorphic.
Are the topological dimensions of $(M_1,\mathcal{M}_1)$ and $(M_2 ,\mathcal{M}_2)$ necessarily the same if the spacetimes are causal?
A spacetime is called casual iff there exists no non-spacelike closed paths in it.

PS:Who knows, if such two non-homeomorphic but causally $\ll$-isomorphic spacetimes are possible, they appear as topological indeterminacy to the causal observer(an observer limited by the constraint of causality), it might be one cause of the quantum indeterminacy.

Obviousely not! Take the Minkowski spacetime in $1+1$ and $1+2$ dimensions, under the identificactions $(t,x) \sim (t+a, x)$ and $(t,x,y) \sim (t,x,y+a)$. They are both causal and $\ll$-isomorphic but not homeomorphic. NOETHELSS, Surya has shown for either past or future distinguishing spacetimes the topological dimension of the underlying space is fixed by the causal structure isomorphism ($\ll$-isomorphism)! So the physical insight might be still revived!
